# How to call a function after the chosen item in FeatureTable is highlighted

Tags: javascript, dom-events, arcgis-js-api

I have a table of routes generated by `FeatureTable` and I have used `setSelectionSymbol` to change the route selected in the table to red.  My problem is I want to confirm the route selection after the route on the map is changed to red and my code asks for confirmation before the route is changed to red.  My code is:

```
     var map, stateBaseMap, geometryLayer, routeFeature, routeDataFeature, myFeatureTable,
        stateBaseMapUrl, geometryLayerUrl, routeFeatureUrl, routeDataFeatureUrl;

  require([ "esri/map",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/dijit/FeatureTable",
             "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
             "esri/Color", 
             "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
              "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
              "esri/geometry/Extent",
              "esri/graphicsUtils",
              "esri/tasks/query",
              "dojo/dom",
              "dojo/parser",
              "dojo/ready",
              "dojo/on"],
    function(Map,
             ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
             ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, 
             GeometryService, 
             FeatureLayer,
             FeatureTable,
             SimpleLineSymbol,
             Color,
             ContentPane, 
             BorderContainer,
             Extent, 
             graphicsUtils, 
             Query,
              dom, 
              parser, 
              ready, 
              on) {
      parser.parse();

      ready(function(){
            esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/llr/llrproxy";
            esri.config.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
            esri.config.defaults.io.corsDetection = false;
            stateBaseMapUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_stateBaseMapServiceURL").value;
            geometryLayerUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_geometryServiceURL").value;
            routeFeatureUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_routeLayerURL").value;
            map = new Map("map");
            stateBaseMap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(stateBaseMapUrl);
            map.addLayer(stateBaseMap);
            geometryLayer = new GeometryService(geometryLayerUrl);
            map.addLayer(geometryLayer);
            
            routeFeature = new FeatureLayer(routeFeatureUrl, {
                mode : FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                outFields : [ "*" ],
                visible:true,
                id : "routeFeature"
            });
            var selectionSymbol = new  SimpleLineSymbol(
                    SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new Color([255,0,0]),
                    4
                  );

            routeFeature.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);

            map.addLayer(routeFeature);
            on(routeFeature, "load", function(){
                loadTable();
                myFeatureTable.on("row-select", function(evt){
                    confirmRoute(evt);
                  });
              });
            function confirmRoute(evt) {
                var message = "Is this the correct route?\nEntry State: "+
                                evt[0].data.ORIGIN  + "\nRoute Description: " +
                                evt[0].data.ROUTE_DESC + "\nExit State: " +
                                evt[0].data.DESTNATION ;
                if (confirm(message) == true) {
                    document.getElementById('shipment_routeText').value = evt[0].data.ROUTE_DESC;
                    var oldAction = document.getElementById("shipment").action;
                    var url = oldAction.replace("shipment","shipment"+"_saveRoute");
                    document.forms[0].action = url;
                    document.forms[0].submit();

                }
            }

            function loadTable(){
                    myFeatureTable = new FeatureTable({
                    featureLayer : routeFeature,
                    map : map, 
                    editable: false,
                    fieldInfos: [
                              {
                                name: 'ROUTE_ID', 
                                visible: false
                              },
                              {
                                name: 'ORIGIN', 
                                alias: 'Entry State'
                              },
                              {
                                name: 'ROUTE_DESC', 
                                alias: 'Route Description'
                              },
                              {
                                name: 'DESTNATION', 
                                alias: 'Exit State'
                              }
                    ]
                  }, 'myTableNode');
    
                  myFeatureTable.startup();
            }
        });
      });
```

I thought by putting the `confirmRoute(evt)` function inside of the `myFeatureTable.on("row-select", function(evt){}` event handler the route would be highlighted first but it isn't.  I am using version 3.16.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the issue by nesting a `update-end` event handler with the `row-select` handler.  I also remove the `update-end` handler after the confirmation. Otherwise, I stack up confirmation windows if I don't click cancel.  Here is the part of the code I changed.

```
                map.addLayer(routeFeature);
            on(routeFeature, "load", function(){
                loadTable();
                myFeatureTable.on("row-select", function(evt){
                    routeChange = routeFeature.on("update-end", function(none){
                                            confirmRoute(evt);
                                        });
                  });
              });
            function confirmRoute(evt) {
                var message = "Is this the correct route?\nEntry State: "+
                                evt[0].data.ORIGIN  + "\nRoute Description: " +
                                evt[0].data.ROUTE_DESC + "\nExit State: " +
                                evt[0].data.DESTNATION ;
                if (confirm(message) == true) {
                    document.getElementById('shipment_gisRouteId').value = evt[0].data.ROUTE_ID;
                    document.getElementById('shipment_routeText').value = evt[0].data.ROUTE_DESC;
                    var oldAction = document.getElementById("shipment").action;
                    var url = oldAction.replace("shipment","shipment"+"_saveRoute");
                    document.forms[0].action = url;
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                }
                routeChange.remove();
            }
```